# Can foreach selectively utilize multiple back-ends (doParallel and doRedis) at the same time?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach, doparallel, r-doredis

I am processing files which are about 1 Gb in size.  The processing can be broken into two steps, one which depends on the large files and a second which depends on a smaller amount of data.  Can I queue some foreach commands for the doParallel back end while queuing other foreach commands with the doRedis back end?

```
foreach() %dopar:doParallel% {
    foreach() %dopar:doRedis% {}
}
```

The goal here is to keep the remote jobs small due to memory and network IO constraints while also utilizing the several local cores I have for the pre/post-processing.

Comment: No, not conceptually. However you will need to specifically lay out how many cores each function uses and assign cues and workers to doRedis and make sure that you close out work functions specifically within each function as you complete a task. Depending on the tasks and how they play with each other you could end up with a tangled mess. You will simply need to try!

Comment: Ok great. Can you point me in the direction of how to dispatch some foreach commands to a doRedis back end and some to a doParallel back end?

Comment: You will need to set up separate functions for each of the tasks and assign the cores in each. It will take some experimenting. Check out this pdf and see if you can figure out how to assign the nodes.https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/doParallel.pdf I think the biggest obstacle will be writing functions which separate the tasks efficiently. Then you can just shunt them to your parallel applications. I am not convinced you need the `foreach` unless you are iterating over something. This pseudocode is not enough to say

Comment: I'm sorry but you aren't being specific enough for me to gain any insight from your comments. There is no information in the pdf you linked.  Regardless the question deals specifically with foreach. (Also, having many tasks implies iterating over something (the tasks, chunks of data)? Foreach is just a convenient interface for the iteration.)

Comment: There is no way to be more specific. You have not given any code to comment on. That script above does nothing except initiate parallels....but nothing happens within them...no work is coded for in that code. There is no way to make a script work more efficiently without seeing the work that it does. You need to include more or you will not get the help you need.